# What is the significance of std::ios_base::Init class in embedded C++ and can it be omitted?

Tags: c++, embedded, c++17, bare-metal

I am writing a code for STM32F4 series of microcontrollers using C++ 17. using arm-none-eabi
g++ version 9.3.1 20200408 (release) (GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain 9-2020-q2-update)

I am using std::tuple, std::variant and few other things that generally bloat the code. But I noticed that my code was way too bloated. So I started playing with linker options and got to the point where the code was breaking because it was missing std::ios_base::Init constructor and destructor. I added blank implementation in the code and everything started working again. I couldnt noticed any issues with the code.

My code dropped from 300k to 65k in O0 optimization and reduced additionally to 17.5k with Os flag.

linker options:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -v -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-use-cxa-atexit -Wall -fstack-usage --specs=nano.specs -mthumb -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--start-group -lm -lc -lgcc -lnosys -T ../../../../../armLib/gcc/STM32F429ZI/System/flash.ld ...
```

Now my question is, am I breaking something by omitting the implementation of the std::ios_base::Init ?
Why is that pulling all locality things that I dont use in the code explicitly? I do use std::string_view, so probably pooled from there..

Just some of the functions included in the code when Init is left.

```
1> 134276844 00001524 W _ZNKSt8time_getIwSt19istreambuf_iteratorIwSt11char_traitsIwEEE21_M_extract_via_formatES3_S3_RSt8ios_baseRSt12_Ios_IostateP2tmPKw
1> 134276844 00001524 t _ZNKSt8time_getIwSt19istreambuf_iteratorIwSt11char_traitsIwEEE21_M_extract_via_formatES3_S3_RSt8ios_baseRSt12_Ios_IostateP2tmPKw.localalias
1> 134315756 00001526 W _ZNKSt7__cxx118time_getIcSt19istreambuf_iteratorIcSt11char_traitsIcEEE21_M_extract_via_formatES4_S4_RSt8ios_baseRSt12_Ios_IostateP2tmPKc
1> 134315756 00001526 t _ZNKSt7__cxx118time_getIcSt19istreambuf_iteratorIcSt11char_traitsIcEEE21_M_extract_via_formatES4_S4_RSt8ios_baseRSt12_Ios_IostateP2tmPKc.localalias
1> 134252068 00001530 W _ZNKSt8time_getIcSt19istreambuf_iteratorIcSt11char_traitsIcEEE21_M_extract_via_formatES3_S3_RSt8ios_baseRSt12_Ios_IostateP2tmPKc
1> 134252068 00001530 t _ZNKSt8time_getIcSt19istreambuf_iteratorIcSt11char_traitsIcEEE21_M_extract_via_formatES3_S3_RSt8ios_baseRSt12_Ios_IostateP2tmPKc.localalias
1>    text     data     bss     dec     hex filename
1>  176460      772   11120  188352   2dfc0 Output/Release External/Exe/Bloaty.elf
```

and then after magic implementation

```
namespace std{
ios_base::Init::Init(){}
ios_base::Init::~Init(){}
}
```

all of that locality stuff is gone and the code is:

```
1>    text     data     bss     dec     hex filename
1>   18824      144    5360   24328    5f08 Output/Release External/Exe/Bloaty.elf
```

Comment: Do you use the standard streams in your code (`cin`, `cout`, `cerr`)?

Comment: Why do you care about the size of your code at O0?

Comment: If you don't include `<iostream>` (you can use `<istream>` and `<ostream>` instead) - do you still get same bloating by `std::ios_base::Init`? It connects with @NathanOliver's question I guess.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I dont use any of the iostream stuff, or istream/ostream. I have no clue why ios_base::Init is included. I would assume its related to the std::string_view. that is the only thing I have related to the strings which could use some locality

Comment: @NathanPierson: example from above is with Os. So its 16K vs 153K (when Init is not overridden). I am concern because I have more code to write .. so 140K is significant.

Comment: @Gossamer `std::ios_base::Init` is used to initialize the static global objects the iostream library uses.  It's purpose is to ensure the streams are created first, thus avoiding the static initialization order fiasco and ensuring other static initializations can use those streams.  If you're not using the streams at all, I don't think it'll hurt you, but I'll leave an answer to someone who is more familiar with the library than myself.

Comment: @NathanPierson : Its an unspecified STM32F4 MCU, variants range from 64Kb to 2Mb of flash.  If you cannot fit the debug build on the part, you cannot debug it.

Comment: I highly recommend searching the compiler documentation to find out how to route `std::cout` and `std::cin` to your embedded system's serial port.  This will allow you to print without writing custom functions.

Comment: You should use `-ffreestanding`. But generally, as soon as you include C++ you get a pile of bloat added to the CRT where it has to run constructors for all objects with static storage duration. You can single step through the constructor calls in the CRT to see which classes that caused the bloat. And from there on hunt down objects of those classes. Or you could just forget about chasing down all this likely useless bloat that clogs up your MCU and switch to a more suitable language for embedded systems. C comes to mind.